# How to track the motion capture of the OTT application using ML

Tags: android, machine-learning, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm building a tool and that will be primarily tracking the user interaction with the OTT application and give us the latency of the frame by frame changing time.

**Example Usecase:**

1. Try to open the youtube app in the android device.
2. Click Search Icon.
3. Enter search Keyword "Machine Learning"
4. All the matching video content will be displayed in the search result.

The above use case, I'm trying to open the Youtube application in the android device.
First thing I just want to get the time interval between clicking the app from the android platform home page to the app (Fully rendered) launch time.

**The action looks like below:**

startTimer(py function) --> Click the app icon in the android home screen (using appium) --> The youtube app is opened and wait until the full page rendered successfully (using appium) --> endTimer (function)

The below piece of code helps me to track the time in between the action that perfomred.

```
import time

t0 = time.time()
//App launch activity or Search activities, and explicit wait logic
t1 = time.time()

total = t1-t0 //CX latency
```

The challenging part is that I'm using some explicit wait till the page transition to get complete but most of time the accuracy is not that much good (total). I just want to start the timer and end the timer in the right place and simultaneously I want to use some pixel to pixel changing algorithm that suites for streaming platform (Not like image comparison algo like OCR) and It should fully monitor the UI changes in the front end application and should help me to get the accurate time once the page is fully render (Like when its become static page).

Can someone give me some high level ML algo/pattern that helps me to get the client side performance latency when there is a transition based on user input (Clicking event, moving one page to another page (Dynamic page)) instead of just comparing actual and expected images using OCR algo.